# Это анонимный класс? Как это работает?

Tags: java, android

Я не так давно в java и вот сегодня увидел такую штуку. Создаем обьект класса и после него сразу открываем фигурные скобки... и в них пишем код.
Вот так

```
private final CameraDevice.StateCallback mStateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onOpened(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice) {
        // This method is called when the camera is opened.  We start  camera preview here.
        mCameraOpenCloseLock.release();
        mCameraDevice = cameraDevice;
        createCameraPreviewSession();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice) {
        mCameraOpenCloseLock.release();
        cameraDevice.close();
        mCameraDevice = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice, int error)   {
        mCameraOpenCloseLock.release();
        cameraDevice.close();
        mCameraDevice = null;
        Activity activity = getActivity();
        if (null != activity) {
            activity.finish();
        }
    }

};
```

определен инстанс и сразу скобки и внутри переопределены 4 метода. Что это вообще значит? Как это будет работать?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Это называется [Анонимный класс](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html). Сразу после вызова конструктора происходил реализация необходимых методов. В случае если класс создаётся на основе интерфейса, то надо будет написать реализацию всех методов. Если же это просто класс, то можно переопределить только нужные методы.